# How to set the state inside useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-effect

I'm new to react, and couldn't find the answer after searching and messing around with the code. I'm making a get request to my server inside a useEffect hook, and trying to take the response and set it as a piece of state. I am getting back the response from the server correctly, but for some reason I can't take the response and set it as some state (setProfile below does nothing). Here is the code:

```
const Profile = () => {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { userid } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/user/${userid}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwt'),
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setProfile(result);
      });
  }, []);
```

What is puzzling is that I am able to set the state just fine in a similar get request:

```
const Profile = () => {
  const [mypics, setPics] = useState([]);
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/myposts', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwt'),
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setPics(result.myposts);
      });
  }, []);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: No error message. My component loads fine.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks. You're right my code shown here is fine, I made the mistake of trying to read the state before it got updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know the state isn't being set? That could point you to the root of your issue. I don't see any errors in your code. What could be happening: setting state is an async operation, meaning that the state is only set once the component has rendered, useEffect was called, the API was called, and then the data was passed to state. If you're trying to read the state value inside that component, and you're getting null—it's not because the state is NEVER set, it's because you're reading the value you set for your initial state before it's updated.

Try passing the state as a prop into another component and seeing if you can read it there.

Apologies if I'm off-base.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You were right that it was being set correctly, and that I was reading the state before it got updated.

Comment: @Michael Glad to hear :) If this was right, would you mind marking it as correct?